# Why do the messages in RabbitMQ queue get lost when consumer is restart?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have set up a RabbitMQ consumer as follows:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import pika
import datetime
import logging
import json
from logging import StreamHandler
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from pika import SelectConnection

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[StreamHandler()],
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format=logging.BASIC_FORMAT)
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class QueueConsumer(object):
    """The consumer class to manage connections to the AMQP server/queue"""

    def __init__(self, queue, logger, parameters, thread_id=0):
        self.channel = None
        self.connection = None
        self.queue_name = queue
        self.logger = logger
        self.consumer_id = 'Thread: %d' % (thread_id,)
        self.parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(**parameters)

    def _on_queue_declared(self, frame):
        self.logger.debug('{} ... declaring queue'.format(self.consumer_id))
        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        try:
            self.channel.basic_consume(self.handle_delivery, queue=self.queue_name, no_ack=True)
            self.logger.info("{} Declared queue...".format(self.consumer_id))
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error('{} crashing:--> {}'.format(self.consumer_id, str(e)))

    def _on_channel_open(self, channel):
        self.channel = channel
        try:
            self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue_name,
                                       exclusive=False,
                                       durable=True,
                                       auto_delete=False,
                                       callback=self._on_queue_declared)
            self.logger.info("{} Opened Channel....".format(self.consumer_id))
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error('{} {}'.format(self.consumer_id, str(e)))

    def _on_connected(self, connection):
        connection.channel(self._on_channel_open)

    def consume(self):
        try:
            self.connection = SelectConnection(self.parameters,
                                               self._on_connected)
            self.connection.ioloop.start()
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error('{} {}'.format(self.consumer_id, str(e)))
            self.connection.close()
            self.connection.ioloop.start()

    def decode(self, body):
        try:
            _body = body.decode('utf-8')
        except AttributeError:
            _body = body

        return _body

    def handle_delivery(self, channel, method, header, body):
        try:
            start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            _logger.info("Received...")
            _logger.info("Content: %s" % body)
            req = json.loads(self.decode(body))

            # Do something
            sleep(randint(10, 100))

            time_taken = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
            _logger.info("[{}] Time Taken: {}.{}".format(
                req.get("to_num"), time_taken.seconds, time_taken.microseconds))

        except Exception as err:
            _logger.exception(err)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    workers = 3
    pika_parameters = OrderedDict([('host', '127.0.0.1'), ('port', 5672), ('virtual_host', '/')])
    try:
        pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers)
        start = 1
        for thread_id in range(start, (workers + start)):
            pool.submit(QueueConsumer('test_queue', _logger, pika_parameters, thread_id).consume)

    except Exception as err:
        _logger.exception(err)
```

I, also, have a queue publisher as below:

```
import uuid
import pika
import logging
import json
from logging import StreamHandler
from pika import SelectConnection

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[StreamHandler()],
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=logging.BASIC_FORMAT)
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class QueuePublisherClient(object):

    def __init__(self, queue, request):
        self.queue = queue
        self.response = None
        self.channel = None
        self.request = request
        self.corrId = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.callBackQueue = None
        self.connection = None
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host="0.0.0.0")
        self.connection = SelectConnection(
            parameters, self.on_response_connected
        )
        self.connection.ioloop.start()

    def on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
        if self.corrId == props.correlation_id:
            self.response = body
            self.connection.close()
            self.connection.ioloop.start()

    def on_response_connected(self, connection):
        _logger.info("Connected...\t(%s)" % self.queue)
        self.connection = connection
        self.connection.channel(self.on_channel_open)

    def on_connected(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.connection.channel(self.on_channel_open)

    def on_channel_open(self, channel):
        # _logger.info("Channel Opened...\t(%s)" % self.queue)
        self.channel = channel
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue,
                                   durable=True,
                                   exclusive=False,
                                   auto_delete=False,
                                   callback=self.on_queue_declared)

    def on_queue_declared(self, frame):
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange="",
                                   routing_key=self.queue,
                                   properties=pika.BasicProperties(),
                                   body=str(self.request))
        self.connection.close()
        _logger.info("Message Published...\t(%s)" % self.queue)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {
        'text': 'This is a sample text',
        'to_num': '+2547xxxxxxxx'
    }
    count = 10000

    for index in range(count):
        data['index'] = index
        QueuePublisherClient("test_queue", json.dumps(data))
```

When I publish 10000 messages to the queue and the consumer is not started, via `rabbitmqctl list_queues` I am able to see that test_queue has 10000 messages. When I start the consumer, I run `rabbitmqctl list_queues` and I see that the queue has 0 messages. However, the consumer is still consuming the messages from the queue. The problem is, when I stop the consumer after a few seconds then restart it, I am unable to recover my messages. How can I evade this?

This is just a simulation of an actual situation whereby the consumer process is restarted by monit and I suffer the loss of messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using the latest version of Pika, to start with.

When you set `no_ack=True` (`auto_ack=True` in Pika 1.0) RabbitMQ considers the message acknowledged when it is delivered. This means that every message that your consumer has in memory (or in the TCP stack) when you stop it will be lost because RabbitMQ considers it acknowledged.

You should use `no_ack=False` (the default) and acknowledge messages in `handle_delivery` once your work is done. Please note that if your work takes a long time you should do it in another thread to prevent blocking Pika's I/O loop.

See the following documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Answer (score 0):

As you already declared prefetch_count to 1 and your queue is durable, So when consumer start it will process messages one by one only. To check the same you can put sleep of 1 sec in your code and try to restart consumer after few seconds. You will see, the processed messages only removed from the queue. if you not set prefetch count then only all messages washed out from your queue one consumer started. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried setting it to 0. Didn't make any difference with regards to my concerns. Also, I've checked the docs and `The prefetch-count is ignored by consumers who have enabled the no-ack option`